# Elementor Posts Widget Custom Query: found_posts return 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom query based on some selected posts in Elementor pro Posts Widget. below is code. The query is displaying posts correctly in Posts widget but found_posts always shows zero value. Can some body help me.

```
 function my_fav_by_user($fav_query) {

    $fav_query->set( 'post__in', array(2783,2780,2793,2528,2873, 2477,2892,2890));
    
    _e("Total Posts=".$fav_query->found_posts, 'my-text-domain');

}
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_fav_query3', 'my_fav_by_user' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue like I'm fetching the IDs of the selected post from a ACF relationship field.

I'm editing my comment again here.

I just found the solution.

```
function related_insights_query( $query ) {
    $postid = get_the_ID(); 
    $ids = get_post_meta($postid, 'call_rel_insights', true);
    if ( $ids ) { $query->set( 'post__in', $ids ); }
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/rel_insights', 'related_insights_query' );
```

get_field was causing an infinite loop.

Comment: 'call_rel_insights' is a ACF relationship field I have used here.

Comment: my specific question is regarding found_posts returning 0.

Comment: found_posts will not work here until you remove the argument 'no_found_rows' => true.
however, it doesn't work. So you have to rearranged the query args

'posts_per_page' => 10,

The post_per_page at the end of the query args results in "0" found_posts. Later shifted to the top of the query args, the query results in the actual result like "100" found_post.

This will be hectic.

If you fetch the selected post through a custom field and use the code I have mentioned, then just count($ids) to display the number of found posts.